# Mudar o tema da navbar do Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Olá,

Procurei muito na internet um método que eu possa mudar o tema da navbar do Bootstrap ao clicar em um botão.

Navbar quando o usuário acessou o site:
[image]

Quando o usuário clicasse no botão:
[image]

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar a classe `navbar-inverse` que faz o efeito que procuras.

Junta um auscultador de eventos que remova essa classe no primeiro clique.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```
$('.navbar-inverse').on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('navbar-inverse');
});
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/7q6chbsL/